# implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

whenever I try to create the channel after running the Network I face this error. however, if prune the fabric and restart my pc and then again create the channel after running the fabric error has gone. But I am not able to debug the error.

Comment: You should probably try to the mailing list of Rocket Chat for this type of non-programming question.

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what actions you are performing.  Can you edit your question to show all the commands you are running, including starting the network?